# VS code doesn't recognize OnTriggerEnter method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to detect a collider in unity3d for a shooting game. I want to write a OnTriggerEnter method but vscode doesn't recognize this method. For example when I write "private void ontr"

VS code doesn't suggest me the method name. I just write the method manually like this

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

}
```

because I always have this kind of problem in VS code but problem is about method itself. Unity doesn't call method either. What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Seyit Süleyman Tekin**! I think your problem is with Monobehaivour's class. VS Code may don't recognize MonoBehaviour. At the beginning of your script

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

in this part, the MonoBehaviour text must have a different colour. If it's not, [can you check this video please](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi-4GyO95d8)

Comment: The problem is actaully beyond that. VS code doesn't recognize any method I am writing, Display, Caller and etc. method too